# How is implied volatility on future treasuries used to expect Forex volatility?

Tags: options, bonds, foreign-exchange, treasury, implied-volatility

I was listening to some traders talk amongst themselves. One emphasized the importance treasury implied Vol as a useful indicator for forex vol/trading.

I don't totally see the connection. I have a vague idea how this maybe true, but was hoping to hear an answer that can explain a clear connection why this maybe true.

Thank you.